# Can I achieve this versatile mixin in SASS?

Tags: sass, mixins

I am attempting to reduce the amount of repitition in the following CSS:

```
$width_altyp_name : 220px;
$width_view_dates : 140px;
$width_alog_status: 60px;

tr,
td {

    line-height: 3;

    .view_date_raised,
    .view_date_sent {
        max-width: $width_view_dates;
        min-width: $width_view_dates;
    }

    .altyp_name {
        max-width: $width_altyp_name;
        min-width: $width_altyp_name;
    }

    .alog_ID {
        max-width: $width_altyp_name;
        min-width: $width_altyp_name;
    }

    .alog_status_text {
        max-width: $width_alog_status;
        min-width: $width_alog_status;
    }
}
```

I am wondering whether I can use @mixin (or anything else) to produce a "function" which will take 2 arguments:

- $classname
- $width

and use that to generate CSS rules in the style of the following:

```
@mixin set-column-width($classname, $width) 
    $classname {
        max-width:  $width;
        min-width:  $width;
    }
}
```

I would hope to then replace much of the above with something like:

```
@include set-column-width(".view_date_raised", $width_view_dates);
@include set-column-width(".altyp_name", $width_altyp_name);
@include set-column-width(".alog_status_text", $width_alog_status_text);
```

Comment: You already did the job, you only missed the [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) on `$classname` in your `@mixin`.

Comment: @Arkellys  Just seen your message - thanks for the link! Much appreciated.  I shall try now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Arkellys for pointing out that all I needed to do was understand [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

My revised SASS is this:

```
    $width_alog_ID    : 60px;
    $width_alog_status: 60px;
    $width_altyp_name : 220px;
    $width_emp_names  : 150px;
    $width_view_dates : 140px;

    @mixin set-column-width($c, $w) {
        #{$c} {
            max-width: $w;
            min-width: $w;
        }
    }

    tr,
    td {
        line-height: 2;

        @include set-column-width('.view_date_raised', $width_view_dates); 
        @include set-column-width('.view_date_sent', $width_view_dates); 
        @include set-column-width('.altyp_name', $width_altyp_name); 
        @include set-column-width('.alog_ID', $width_alog_ID); 
        @include set-column-width('.alog_status_text', $width_alog_status); 
        @include set-column-width('.emp_drafter', $width_emp_names); 
        @include set-column-width('.emp_sender', $width_emp_names); 
    }
```